# how can I iterate through list of list in "pyspark" for a specific result

Tags: python, pyspark

I am new to PySpark, I am trying to understand how I can do this. Any help appreciated.

I have this RDD for example :

```
[[u'merit', u'release', u'appearance'], [u'www.bonsai.wbff.org'], [u'whitepages.com'], [u'the', u'childs', u'wonderland', u'company'], [u'lottery']]
```

I try to have :

```
[[(u'merit',1), (u'release',1), (u'appearance',1)], [(u'www.bonsai.wbff.org',1)], [(u'whitepages.com',1)], [(u'the',1), (u'childs',1), (u'wonderland',1), (u'company',1)], [(u'lottery',1)]]
```

But all I've tried, it gets me either this result :

```
[[u'merit', u'release', u'appearance',1], [u'www.bonsai.wbff.org',1], [u'whitepages.com',1], [u'the', u'childs', u'wonderland', u'company',1], [u'lottery',1]]
```

or these errors:

- `TypeError: 'PipelinedRDD' object is not iterable`
- `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'foreach'` - or `split`, `take`, etc.

I tried this :

```
rdd1=rdd.map(lambda r : (r,1))
```

I have the first result :

```
[u'merit', u'release', u'appearance',1], [u'www.bonsai.wbff.org',1], [u'whitepages.com',1], [u'the', u'childs', u'wonderland', u'company',1], [u'lottery',1]]

rdd1=rdd.map(lambda r : (r[:][0],1))
```

It gets just the first word in each line, it's not what I want

```
for row in rdd.collect() : row.foreach(lambda x : (x,1)) 
# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'foreach'
```

```
rdd3.take(100).foreach( lambda a : (a.foreach( lambda e : print(e,1)))) 
# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'foreach'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To print `collect` and iterate locally:

```
for xs in rdd3.take(100):
    for x in xs:
        print(x)
```

To iterate in general:

```
rdd.flatMap(lambda xs: [(x, 1) for x in xs])
```

Comment: I have a follow-up question, dropping the link, thanks in advance! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61823544/pyspark-mapping-multiple-columns @user7337271